# how can I get job submitting time and use it in Flink application?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep, flink-sql, flinkml

I'm currently developing a stream processing application, one of the functionality is to take events that happen in the time zone [time of submitting the job, time of submitting the job + T ].

how can access to that particular variable (time of submitting the job) with stream processing APIs in Flink?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to use Flink's `ParameterTool`

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/dev/best_practices.html#getting-your-configuration-values-into-the-parametertool

```
ParameterTool parameters = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);

// set up the execution environment
final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
env.getConfig().setGlobalJobParameters(parameters);
```

You can pass the timestamp through CLI parameters or simply get the system time in java code. With `GlobalJobParameters`, you can access the time in any operators through the `context`.